# Using Dynamic choice parameter as a label in batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

The Jenkins build had  Dynamic choice parameter 'choice_database' with value 'Oracle'.

Using 'choice_database' as label for windows batch script on Jenkins doesn't work

```
 GOTO %choice_database%
wmic process where "CommandLine like '%%java.exe -Dlog4j.configuration%%' and Caption Like '%%java.exe%%'" call terminate
wmic process where "CommandLine like '%%-Djava.util.logging.file=%%' and Caption Like '%%java.exe%%'" call terminate

:%choice_database%
wmic process where "CommandLine like '%%start.cmd%%' and Caption Like '%%cmd.exe%%'" call terminate
```

This is what Jenkins outputs

> GOTO Oracle
>
> The system cannot find the batch label specified - Oracle
>
> Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
> Finished: FAILURE

Is there some other syntax for labels when using parameterized values for batch scripts on Jenkins?

Comment: `GOTO %choice_database%` means: jump to the label with the name defined in environment variable `choice_database`. Is there an environment variable `choice_database`?  Yes, your batch files does not have lines starting with a colon and all the possible string values the variable can have. `:%choice_database%` is not valid. It is not possible to define a label which name depends on current value of an environment variable. Open a command prompt window, run `goto /?` and read the output help.

Comment: This is the answer which I was looking for _**It is not possible to define a label which name depends on current value of an environment variable**_

Comment: and, this is not much of a help :) `C:\Windows>goto /?
Directs cmd.exe to a labeled line in a batch program.
GOTO label
  label   Specifies a text string used in the batch program as a label.
You type a label on a line by itself, beginning with a colon.
If Command Extensions are enabled GOTO changes as follows:
GOTO command now accepts a target label of :EOF which transfers control to the end of the current batch script file.  This is an easy way to
exit a batch script file without defining a label.`